# SSMS Copy and Paste to Excel - DateTime Columns

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, ssms

I am not sure if this is a T-SQL / SSMS issue, or Excel.  I am hoping there is something I can do inside my SQL that can accomodate for this, but I haven't been able to find a solution via web-searches.  I have a query that pulls a Date / Time column.  It shows in SSMS as:  2020-12-24 03:30:27.0000000

However, when I copy this value into Excel, it shows like this:  30:27.0

As such, I need to go into Excel and format each column.  Is there a way I can write my SQL statement to avoid having to do this?  I am not doing anything in my SQL statement except:  SELECT DateColumn FROM Table. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    '"' + CONVERT(varchar,CAST([DateColumn] as datetime2)) + '"'
FROM 
    [Table]
```